# Button not working in headless mode (chromedriver)

Tags: javascript, python, selenium-webdriver

I've been trying to find a solution to this problem for a while, but to no avail. I am writing a webscraping program for a website that requires a user to login to access the data (not against T&S). Loging in involves entering the username and password into two input fields contained in a form field. However, I cannot figure out how to press the sign in button! Here are some olutions that work while not in headless mode, and that don't work while browser is headless:

- Pressing enter while in the password input will submit the form
- Clicking the sign in button will submit the form
- Locating the form element and using `form_element.click()` submits the form
- Locating the sign in button's x and y positions, moving the cursor over the element using `ActionChains`, then performing a click using `ActionChains` will submit the form

I can't think of any other methods for submitting the form/clicking the sign in button. I'm wondering if the website has some sort of protection against headless mode that blocks me from signing in while operating a headless browser. I've seen a few other people who have run into this problem, and most of the solutions were to wait for the element to be clickable, but I already do that and I know for sure that the element is being located since I would receive a timeout error if it wasn't, and it works while not in headless mode.

These are the options I'm working with:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument("--log-level=3")
options.add_argument("--disable-logging")
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-extensions')
options.add_argument("--dns-prefetch-disable")
options.add_argument("enable-automation")
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
options.add_argument("--geoenable=true")
options.add_argument("--remote-debugging-pipe")
prefs = {"credentials_enable_service": False,
    "profile.password_manager_enabled": False,
    "profile.default_content_setting_values.geolocation": 1
}
```

And this is the relevant code:

```
username = "---"
password = "---"
driver.get("website")
driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(3)
email_input = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[data-testid="email_input"]'))) 
email_input.send_keys(username)
password_input = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[data-testid="password_input"]') 
password_input.send_keys(password)
form = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "form.styles__form__jBI8X")
form.submit()
```

Here is the relevant html data:

Also, here is the relevant html code:

```
<form class="styles__form__jBI8X"> 
  <div> 
    <input" data-testid="email_input"> 
  </div> 
  <div> 
    <input" data-testid="password_input"> 
  </div> 
  <button data-testid="sign-in-button">Sign in</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Put the Relevant HTML fragment in the question itself, not in the comments.